# Date getting truncated on PDI 7.1 for salesforce DB - Need workaround

Tags: etl, pentaho

We are working on transformation which inserts date into a salesforce DB and are seeing issues.

Below are the issues: A transformation working in PDI CE 6.1 do not work in CE 7.1 or CE 8.3.

Error :

> 2019/10/31 15:46:32 - Salesforce Insert.0 - :Errors were found on item 0 Error code is: INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD Error message: Job Start Time: value not of required type: 2019-10-31T15:46:29.211Z

## On 6.1:

The script was inserting a string variable into date field on SF DB and was working fine.

## For 7.1:

We changed string to date datatype using select values step and executed, the step now inserts data but we saw that the date is shown as one day prior and time as 8PM

## For 8.3:

We changed the date generation step to a javascript step, then changed the data type to date. here the insert works ok. Now if we run the transformation in 7.1 it again truncates the time field.

This seems to be the defect - https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-16480

We would like to know If anyone have encountered this issues, or Is there any workaround for this issue in 7.1 ? i.e. can any Jar file for salesforce be copied from 6.1 or 8.3 version to 7.1 to make this work?

Comment: Hi - I'm going to give you an upvote for quite a good first question, but it could perhaps be improved by adding the actual code changes that you have made so that people can see what you've done. You could also tag it with the underlying database that you are using? (comment too long - continued...)

Comment: I know nothing about Salesforce but AIUI, it uses Oracle but you could perhaps confirm that? BTW, I deleted the phrase "Immediate reply appreciated..." - of course an immediate reply would be, but this is a **volunteer** forum and those helping are taking their own time for free to help you. If you want immediate answers, then you'll have to hire a consultant :-(  p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)